# PHP check for empty fields

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to arrays and how to check for empty vars and my php form tells me T_String expected '(' and I can't see why - mainly because I don't know what I'm doing!!
Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this:

```
<?php
$errors   = array();
$missing  = array();
$required = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'address', 'postcode', 'email', 'dated', 'signature');

if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    for each $name in $required {
        if($_POST($name) = '') {
            $missing.add($name);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: for each $name in $required {, is this the another syntax for this ? Please correct your syntax

Comment: have a look at your syntax of the `foreach` loop. and you should really learn what you're doing...

Comment: So many things wrong with the syntax. You should recheck.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing java here too? $missing.add($name); should be $missing[] = $name;

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
<?php 

$errors = array();
$missing = array();

$required = array(
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
    'address',
    'postcode',
    'email',
    'dated',
    'signature'
);

if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    foreach($required as $name) {
        if(!isset($_POST[$name]) || $_POST[$name]=='') {
            array_push($missing, $name);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

[DEMO HERE](http://codepad.org/otw4Q8u8)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$errors = array();
$missing = array();
  $required = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'address', 'postcode', 'email', 'dated', 'signature');
    if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
      foreach ($required as $name) {
        if(!isset($_POST[$name]) || $_POST[$name] == '') {
          array_push($missing,$name);
        }
      }
    }
 ?>
```

In if condition you should check not assign.

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever locked at [PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) , [COUNT](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) and [EMPTY](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) functions in at php.net?

please be sure that you used the correct syntax and methods to check values

Comment: This is really more of a comment

Comment: it's because of i don't have permission to post comments on questions.